# Maitaining a .sty file with its own .tex documentation

Tags: packages

I would to maintain in the same file :

- a set a macro
- a `.tex` document documenting it

It would look like

```
% macros.sty  
% The macros part
\def\N{\mathbb{N}}
\def\Z{\mathbb{Z}}
\def\C{\mathbb{C}}

% The documenting part
\section*{Mathematical objects}
The commands \verb+\N+, \verb+\Z+ and \verb+\C+ prints $\N$, $\Z$ and $\C$.
```

How could I achieve that easily? My first idea is to write a script that comments all uncommented lines and uncomments all commented lines. It would produce a `.tex` document from the `.sty` file. (So the "documenting part" should be commented in the `.sty` file)

Do you think of a better solution?

Thanks

Comment: Have you looked into the aptly named “doc” package? Try running `texdoc doc`. If that gives you the wrong file for some reason (`texdoc -l doc` gets 517 hits), try `texdoc shortvrb` instead.

Comment: Completely off-topic: it is a bad idea to define such short commands.

Comment: @Johannes_B Why so?

Comment: The shorter a command is, the higher is the Chance another package defined it. Especially with your syntax, you would redefine them without any warning.

Comment: Related: http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/212776/107497

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My solution to this problem is to write the `.sty` file as

```
% macros.presty  
% The macros part
\def\N{\mathbb{N}}
\def\Z{\mathbb{Z}}
\def\C{\mathbb{C}}

%__%%The documenting part
%__%\section*{Mathematical objects}
%__%The commands \verb+\N+, \verb+\Z+ and \verb+\C+ prints $\N$, $\Z$ and $\C$.
```

Then I have a script that transforms this `macros.presty` into a `.sty` file or a `.tex` file. The script decides to keep a line (or not) whether it starts by `%__%`.

Answer (score 7):

Packages for LaTeX2e often are maintained using the **dtx** format.

**.dtx-files** are text files with the file name extension .dtx that contain both the package documentation and the user manual and the code of the .sty-files etc and the commenting on that code.

When you write a .dtx file, usually the documentation-part is written using the **doc** package.

Usually you get a pdf file containing documentation, manual and probably commented sources by compiling that .dtx file with a (pdf)LaTeX-compiler.

For extracting/generating the .sty-files etc from a .dtx file, usually the **docstrip** package is used.

Often people write text files with file name extension **.ins** .
These .ins-files contain directives for extracting/generating .sty-files and the like from .dtx-files.
When compiling an .ins-file with (La)TeX, that .ins-file will load the **docstrip** package and by means of that package the directives for extracting/generating .sty-files and the like from .dtx-files will be carried out.

But you can also have a section within the .dtx-file itself which causes loading **docstrip** and extracting/generating .sty-files and the like before further processing the .dtx-file for creating the .pdf-file containing package documentation, user manual and commented sources and the like.

Here are a few links to CTAN in case you are interested in the dtx format and in the packages **doc** and **docstrip**:

**docstrip** — Remove comments from file: https://www.ctan.org/pkg/docstrip

**doc**  — Format LaTeX documentation: https://www.ctan.org/pkg/doc

**dtxtut**  — Tutorial on writing .dtx and .ins files: https://www.ctan.org/pkg/dtxtut

**DTXGALLERY**: https://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/info/dtxgallery

Answer (score 2):

The standard mechanism for doing what you say used by the latex sources and possibly the majority of contributed packages is the `doc/docstrip` system, however if you feel like a change and something closer to the format in your question, if you save this as `macros.sty`

```
% macros.sty 
\ifcat a@
% The macros part
\RequirePackage{amsfonts}
\def\N{\mathbb{N}}
\def\Z{\mathbb{Z}}
\def\C{\mathbb{C}}


\expandafter\endinput\fi

% The documenting part
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{macros}
\begin{document}
\section*{Mathematical objects}
The commands \verb+\N+, \verb+\Z+ and \verb+\C+ prints $\N$, $\Z$ and $\C$.
\end{document}
```

then `pdflatex macros.sty`  will produce

[image]