# How does the `LaTeXdemo` environment in `siunitx.dtx` be defined?

Tags: siunitx, dtx

I want to translate the `siunitx.pdf` to another language, so I have to read the `siunitx.dtx` and make use of some source code in it. But I have problem to write my own `.tex` file when I meet the `LaTeXdemo` environment in the source file. There is a source code segment in `siunitx.dtx`:

```
\lstnewenvironment{LaTeXdemo}[1][code and example]
  {
    \global\let\lst@intname\@empty
    \expandafter\let\expandafter\LaTeXdemo@end
      \csname LaTeXdemo@#1@end\endcsname
    \@nameuse{LaTeXdemo@#1}
  }
  {\LaTeXdemo@end}
```

I copy it to my `.tex` file and write as follows:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{listings,siunitx}
\makeatletter
\lstnewenvironment{LaTeXdemo}[1][code and example]
  {
    \global\let\lst@intname\@empty
    \expandafter\let\expandafter\LaTeXdemo@end
      \csname LaTeXdemo@#1@end\endcsname
    \@nameuse{LaTeXdemo@#1}
  }
  {\LaTeXdemo@end}
\makeatother
\begin{document}
\begin{LaTeXdemo}
  \num{12345,67890} \\
  \num{1+-2i}       \\
  \num{.3e45}       \\
  \num{1.654 x 2.34 x 3.430}
\end{LaTeXdemo}
\end{document}
```

However, I don't get the expected result as shown in `siunitx.pdf`. There is not the corresponding output result. How to solve this problem?
[image]

Comment: The full definition of `\LaTeXdemo` is larger, including all the helper macros and definitions it runs from line 191 to line 366 in the current [`siunitx.dtx`](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/siunitx/siunitx.dtx).

Comment: I add all of the segment as you said  to my `.tex` file but I get the error : `! Undefined control sequence. \LaTeXdemo@input->\MakePercentComment.....`

Comment: Of course there could be other dependencies. You could try adding everything, but probably it is the easiest to copy the full `.dtx`, make translations in that file, and run LaTeX on the `.dtx` (see https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/212776/what-exactly-happens-when-latex-runs-on-a-dtx-file).

Answer (score 2):

The latest version of `siunitx` (v3) will be released soon. It has separate `.tex` and `.dtx` files, meaning that the code is perhaps a little clearer:

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{listings,siunitx}
\makeatletter
\lst@RequireAspects{writefile}
\newsavebox\LaTeXdemo@box
\lstnewenvironment{LaTeXdemo}[1][code and example]
  {%
    \global\let\lst@intname\@empty
    \edef\LaTeXdemo@end{%
      \expandafter\noexpand\csname LaTeXdemo@@#1@end\endcsname
    }%
    \@nameuse{LaTeXdemo@@#1}%
  }
  {\LaTeXdemo@end}
\newcommand\LaTeXdemo@new[3]{%
  \@namedef{LaTeXdemo@@#1}{#2}%
  \@namedef{LaTeXdemo@@#1@end}{#3}%
}
\newcommand*\LaTeXdemo@common{%
  \setkeys{lst}
    {%
       basicstyle   = \small\ttfamily,
       basewidth    = 0.51em,
       gobble       = 2,
       language     = [LaTeX]{TeX},
    }%
}
\newcount\LaTeXdemo@count
\newcommand*\LaTeXdemo@input{%
  \catcode`\^^M = 10\relax
  \input{\jobname-\number\LaTeXdemo@count.tmp}%
}
\LaTeXdemo@new{code and example}{%
  \setbox\LaTeXdemo@box=\hbox\bgroup
    \global\advance\LaTeXdemo@count by 1 %
    \lst@BeginAlsoWriteFile{\jobname-\number\LaTeXdemo@count.tmp}%
    \LaTeXdemo@common
}{%
    \lst@EndWriteFile
  \egroup
  \begin{center}
    \ifdim\wd\LaTeXdemo@box > 0.48\linewidth
      \begin{minipage}{\linewidth}
        \usebox\LaTeXdemo@box
      \end{minipage}%
      \par
      \begin{minipage}{\linewidth}
        \LaTeXdemo@input
      \end{minipage}
    \else
      \begin{minipage}{0.48\linewidth}
        \LaTeXdemo@input
      \end{minipage}%
      \hfil
      \begin{minipage}{0.48\linewidth}
        \usebox\LaTeXdemo@box
      \end{minipage}%
    \fi
  \end{center}
}
\LaTeXdemo@new{code and float}{%
  \global\advance\LaTeXdemo@count by 1 %
  \lst@BeginAlsoWriteFile{\jobname-\number\LaTeXdemo@count.tmp}%
  \LaTeXdemo@common
}{%
  \lst@EndWriteFile
  \LaTeXdemo@input
}
\LaTeXdemo@new{code only}{\LaTeXdemo@common}{}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
\begin{LaTeXdemo}
  \num{12345,67890}  \\
  \num{.3e45}        \\
\end{LaTeXdemo}
\end{document}
```

You'll see there is some common code, used to collect up the demo verbatim, then a choice of what to do with it. In your attempt, you don't have the common code, only the part that does a demo and code next to each other.

Comment: Most of the manual is the same text between v2 and v3, although the keys are reworked and a few interfaces are altered.

Comment: That really works! Thanks a lot!